# How is depth buffer written to?

Tags: unity, shaders, depth-buffer

As far as I know you normally can't read and write to the same render target in the same shader pass. But if I understand correctly, depth tests rely on depth writes of things being drawn in the same pass (otherwise it'd always be the depth of the last fragment drawn which don't have to be ordered) so how is that being done exactly?

I think this should have many answers but for some reason I could find no articles about depth writing. So I'm hoping someone could share where I can learn about this information.

---

One other thing I wonder: Is it possible to write to the depth buffer in a custom way?
For example, I think the depth buffer is normally written to the same way the geometry is drawn as specified by depth testing comparison (e.g. only closest objects, "Less" depth comparison). But could I instead choose to write the depth of furthest fragments (e.g. "Greater" depth comparison), and draw color as closest as usual.

I guess the answer is no because you would need two depth buffers and I assume the tools don't exist to write shaders (without using multiple passes).

I'll tag this as Unity since that is what I'm most familiar with but I assume the answers will generalize to other graphic frameworks too.

Comment: You might find https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-7/ interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so how is that being done exactly?

There is one part of the pipeline that's allowed to both read and write from the render target: the blending unit at the final stage. This has specialized hardware that's only configurable in a fixed function fashion, so it can read the colour to blend with, blend, and write the result atomically, in a correctly ordered sequence with all other fragments in flight.

Naturally, this serialized access can be a bottleneck, which is part of the reason why transparent blending is more expensive, and why fill rate is often our limiting factor in GPU rendering. There's a limit to how fast we can force all our writes through even this specialized and very fast hardware unit.

A similar thing happens with the depth value, where depending on your depth testing and writing settings the depth value is compared and possibly overwritten in a single operation.

Because this unit is so performance-critical, in shader models to date it's stayed on a fixed function model, unavailable for you to customize programmatically beyond turning depth testing and writes on/off, or changing the comparison used. That keeps the circuitry simple and fast, with exactly predictable execution time for scheduling — all stuff that gets more complicated if we were to inject customized programs into this stage.

You may object that the depth buffer can also be read earlier in the pipeline, for "early z rejection" to skip executing the fragment shader for fragments that are going to fail the depth test later anyway. This optimization can use a conservative depth estimate though — possibly not yet taking into account writes that are still in flight. If a few fragments leak through because the read was out of date, the depth test at the end still ensures we get the correct result. If the rendering configuration does not allow such a conservative z test (ie. a write in flight might make an occluded fragment no longer occluded) then the early z rejection is disabled.

> could I instead choose to write the depth of furthest fragments (e.g. "Greater" depth comparison), and draw color as closest as usual.

No. There are not really two separate writes happening here, just one. Either the depth test passes, and both colour and depth are written (if colour and depth writes are enabled, respectively), or the depth test fails, and neither are written.

So while you can change the direction of the depth test to less-than or greater-than, the same test is always used for the whole fragment, both colour and depth components.

You can control what depth to output in the fragment shader by writing a value to the special `DEPTH` semantic, but doing so disables that early z rejection optimization. The hardware pipeline can no longer determine whether the fragment will be occluded until the fragment shader has been run, so it has to run the full shader even for fragments which will never be seen.

You could achieve something similar to this with multiple passes, rendering your content once with a "Less" test and saving the resulting depths to one buffer, then rendering your content a second time with a "Greater" test, and reading the buffer you previously saved to do whatever computations you want that rely on knowing both the greatest and least depth values at a point.

You may also want to look into the technique of ["depth peeling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_peeling) which is used in some order-independent transparency approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much for the perfect in depth answer. One last other thing I was wondering is what would happen in regards to the depth writes if say in Unity you had a shader with `ZTest Always` and `ZWrite On`? Would the resulting depth be of the closest geometry, or would it be of the last drawn fragment?

Comment: It would be whichever fragment drew last, which is up to the order the triangles were submitted for rendering.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write custom values to the depth buffer, one option is to render the appropriate geometry while disabling writes to the colour buffer, but enabling writes to the depth buffer.

For example, if you want to render a transparent mesh while hiding all of the internal polygons then you can render it twice. The first time you want to render it with colour writes disabled, and depth writes enabled. The second render wants colour writes enabled, depth writes disabled, and the depth test set to equal. Note that for that process to work, you need to make sure that the depth only rendering happens immediately before the transparent rendering or it won't look right.